# Control in Thread class doesn't come back after super.run() call

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a threadfactory, executor, thread class and a runnable class.
Here is the thread class: (threadsCount is an AtomicInteger that I use to keep track of number of threads created)

```
public void run() {
    try {
        threadsCount.incrementAndGet();
        super.run();
    } finally {
        threadsCount.decrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

and my runnable class is currently not implemented but has empty run() method.

When I try to call Executor.execute(new RunnableClazz()), control comes to this Thread class - run() method and when it encounters super.run(), it goes to the RunnableClazz#run() method.

All these are fine. But problem is, after the RunnableClazz#run() is completed, the control doesn't come back to 'finally' block of my Thread class.

Any ideas? Do I need to manully kill the runnable at the end of run() method?

```
public class ThreadAA extends Thread {

private static final AtomicInteger threadsCount = new AtomicInteger();
private static final AtomicInteger threadsCreated = new AtomicInteger();
public static final String DEFAULT_NAME = "ThreadAA";

public ThreadAA(Runnable r)
    {
        this(r, DEFAULT_NAME);
    }
public ThreadAA(Runnable r, String threadName)
    {
        super(r, threadName + "-" + threadsCreated.incrementAndGet());

        setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
        {
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
            {
                logger.error("Uncaught exception in thread " + t.getName(), e);
            }
        });
    }

@Override
public void run()
    {
        boolean debug = false;
        //just for debug purpose
        debug = true;
        if(debug)
        {
            logger.debug("Running thread " + getName());
        }

        try
        {
            threadsCount.incrementAndGet();
            super.run();
        }
        finally
        {
            threadsCount.decrementAndGet();
            if(debug)
            {
                logger.debug("Done running thread " + getName());
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

My RunnableClass:

```
public class RunnableClazz implements Runnable {

@Override
public void run() {
        logger.debug("Inside RunnableClazz");
}

}
```

The method that calls this runnable looks like this:

```
  Executor executor = new Executor(25, 100, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5), new TFactory("abc"));

    executor.setRejectedExecutionHandler(new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());        
    executor.execute(new RunnableClazz());  

executor.execute(new RunnableClazz());
```

Please note that, I create the executor just once during server startup. I have pasted it just to give an idea on how I create it.
So `executor.execute(new RunnableClazz());` creates the issue.

Comment: Can you show a complete example that reproduces the behaviour? In particular, it is not clear what `super` is in your code.

Comment: my guess is your runnable never finishes.

Comment: I have just added the complete code.....

Comment: @NathanHughes - My runnable finishes. I am able to say that because, I can see the last line getting executed of my run method in the runnable class.

Comment: "the control doesn't come back to 'finally' block of my Thread class" where does it go then?

Comment: @Luciano - no idea...

Comment: Is your thread interrupted?

Comment: Doesn't look like it is interrupted. May be it is. What I found during debugging is, the runnable gets executed but later, the code doesn't move beyond while loop in java's ThreadPoolExecutor#run() method. Is there a possibility that some other thread takes over?

Answer (score 2):

I copied your code and started debugging.

When you call super.run() it runs the one from ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
    public void run() {
        runWorker(this);
    }
```

runWorker then calls RunnableClazz.run(), and after that is finished, it puts the thread on hold, waiting for new runnables to be executed. How did this happened?

In the threadFactory, which I assume it's something like this:

```
public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
    return new ThreadAA(r);
}
```

the Runnable r is not your RunnableClazz, but the ThreadPoolExecutor.

**EDIT:**

You may want to extend the ThreadPoolExecutor class and implement the methods:

```
protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) { }

protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) { }
```

and implement your counting there.

Comment: @Override
 public Thread newThread(Runnable r)
 {
  logger.debug("Pool Name:"+poolName);
  return new ThreadAA(r, poolName);
 }

Comment: Yes, I have beforeExecute, afterExecute and terminated overridded.